# reduce DOMPDF generated file size

Tags: php, dompdf

iam using dompdf to generate pdf file from html , the problem is the generated filesize is big ,i.e. 1MB for 1 page of pdf !
is there any way to reduce it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

fonts and images are the primary size issue, use the internal fonts, so you don't have to embed them, and make sure any images are optimised.

> PDFs include support by default for Helvetica, Times-Roman, Courier and Zapf-Dingbats. You do not need to install any font files if you wish to use these fonts. This has the advantage of reducing the size of the resulting PDF, because additional fonts must be embedded in the PDF. 
>   http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Installation

Comment: Thats true , but why default fonts not render correctly , its appear as squares !

Comment: `Any character not supported will typically show up as an unfilled square. DOMPDF does not attempt to find a replacement font for unsupported characters.` http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode

Comment: try tcpdf, its faster and looks like it has better font support.

Comment: FYI, support for font subsetting is in development and will likely be available in the next release of dompdf.

Comment: @BrianS Good News , but my customer wont wait until next release :(

Comment: @shox I wouldn't expect them to, but at least you know it's there. If you want to try it out you can [check out a "nightly" release](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/).

Comment: As @BrianS commented, the actual version of DOMPDF (v0.6.1) has this feature for font subsetting and it makes PDF files much more smaller when using unicode fonts.

Comment: @BillyG Subsetting doesn't work if you need Cyrilic or Greek (Deja Vu font). Shows offset error. Help?

Comment: @MarkoAleksić if you have a question make a new post, not reply to an answer on an old one

Comment: In my case, image was the issue. Reducing image size, reduced the PDF file size drastically.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), using the following config can reduce the file size drastically:

**config/dompdf.php**

```
"enable_font_subsetting" => true,
```

I reduced the pdf size from 4.2 MB to 34 KB in this way.

Comment: Awesome!!! The PDF reduced its size drastically.. Thank you

Comment: After I install barryvdh/laravel-dompdf in laravel. I did not get dompdf.php file in config folder.

Comment: @Y.JoyCh.Singha   `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"` https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#configuration

Comment: @IgorStephano , can you tell me the process of how you reduced the pdf file size?

Comment: I did the same thing, but the size still remained the same.