# DOMPDF - memory leak issue

Tags: html, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3. I got this php error when the system generating many pdf.

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 639 bytes) in /home/deal4uco/public_html/lib/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/font_binary_stream.cls.php on line 144

The font file is big. Almost 24MB+. I believe the dompdf have made it as cache (1.5M+). I don't think the memory issue is related with font file.

Can i know what the problem cause it? Many people said the html contant cannot include these html tag (table, tr, td). Is it really that cause the above issue?

Comment: The problem *is* likely due to the font file. If you disable font subsetting I believe the PDF will process. Right now php-font-lib can run into memory issues when processing large fonts.

Comment: i guess the issue is caused by font file. Because our pdf will contain chinese, so the subsetting is enabled from dompdf. Can i know any solution for coping this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't really have one right now. You can disable subsetting, but a PDF of that size would be unreasonable. Your other option would be to try rendering the PDF out of process (e.g. using `exec`) to see if the smaller process load (and typical greater memory limit for command line PHP) gets you through.

Comment: I am wondering why the font subsetting will get more memory. I have one pdf got embedded subset (ArialUnicodeMs). The pdf can display chinese, and the file size is 97KB++. I never use additional chinese font. Because many pdf software usually install their embedded subset. So i want to ask any solution can reduce memory usage as the default font file is embedded from software.
refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793828/reduce-dompdf-generated-file-size

Comment: A font that is not subsetted doesn't require any extra processing and so takes up little memory. When a font is processed for subsetting (or even just loading into dompdf) php-font-lib has to do a lot of work to parse out all the necessary information. On a desktop system you don't have the same memory limits, nor do you have the same limits when running via command line. Have you tried my suggestion to run out-of-process?

Comment: I set DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING to false in dompdf_config.inc.php. And have added font file (arialuni.ttf) in dompdf\lib\fonts. The font file almost 20MB++. I have include this font name in dompdf_font_family_cache.dist. Code is: 'arialuni' => array ( 'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'ARIALUNI', 'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'ARIALUNI', 'italic'=>  DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'ARIALUNI', 'bold_italic' =>DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'ARIALUNI', ).

The dompdf have reduced 20MB memory usage for one new pdf. The issue is here. Why want to load many memory when the font is embedded from adobe pdf reader software.

Comment: This discussion is getting overly long for StackOverflow. Would you like to continue on the [support group](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/)?